# Helm Secret Concatenate two values in helm secret issue

Tags: go, kubernetes-helm, secret-key

I have a value:

```
test_id = 'test_'
```

I want to concatenate this string with uuidv4 in secret like:

test_111332asdf44

I am trying to do like below:

```
data:
      id: "{{ printf "%s%s" test_id uuidv4 | b64encode }}"
```

But, it gives an error of invalid syntax.

Comment: Have you tried without double quotes, like: _id: {{ printf "%s%s" test_id uuidv4 | b64encode }}_ ?

Comment: Yes, that gives error.

Comment: What's the exact error?  Where is `test_id` defined?